# Docker bind mount goes out of sync

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-volume

I am building a system where files are first uploaded through Django and then are served by Nginx. I am using Docker Compose for deployment, so the data between containers is shared using volumes. Particularly for file uploads, bind mount is used:

```
django:
  volumes:
    - ./uploads:/app/uploads:rw

nginx:
  volumes:
    - ./uploads:/app/uploads:ro
```

Right after the upload everything works as expected: uploaded file is 'propagated' everywhere, I see it on the host machine, Nginx serves it nicely, no problems whatsoever. But after some time Nginx begins to return 404s and when I inspect the directories manually, I see that the source directory on the host and the directories inside the containers are out of sync:

```
user@host:/home/user/site/uploads$ ls -la
total 13068
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root       4096 Jan 23 19:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 user user     4096 Jan 23 10:33 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   12527329 Jan 23 01:49 YbqY7GeoNiK.MP4
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     748081 Jan 23 10:42 dP4va0IpGzM.gif
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      90296 Jan 23 10:52 lKsDoxhDpWE.jpg

user@host:/home/user/site$ docker compose exec nginx sh
# cd /app/uploads/
# ls -la
total 34372
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 23 02:17 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Jan 24 02:01 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        111086 Jan 23 00:27 C4RUNvZTWAZ.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          9652 Jan 20 12:39 JMMMFzFMzr4.png
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       7434720 Jan 23 02:17 YLrOkzve1ck.exe
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      13810152 Jan 22 15:31 YbqY7GeoNiK.MP4
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      13810152 Jan 22 15:31 y4qQWUgPTpv.MOV

user@host:/home/user/site$ docker compose exec django sh
# cd /app/uploads
# ls -la
total 34372
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Jan 23 02:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4096 Jan 24 02:01 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   111086 Jan 23 00:27 C4RUNvZTWAZ.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     9652 Jan 20 12:39 JMMMFzFMzr4.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7434720 Jan 23 02:17 YLrOkzve1ck.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13810152 Jan 22 15:31 YbqY7GeoNiK.MP4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13810152 Jan 22 15:31 y4qQWUgPTpv.MOV
```

The contents of the source directory reflects how it actually should be, and the directories inside the containers are confusing to me: some outdated files mixed with the correct ones.

I also noticed that the containers have unexpected (lower) uptimes, so they seem to crash and restart due to the restart policy (`restart: unless-stopped`):

```
user@host:/home/user/site$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  CREATED        STATUS
8796a4afcda6   site-nginx             9 hours ago    Up 9 hours
7fb35c827d01   site-django            9 hours ago    Up 9 hours
b8044f3c3c0f   site-cron              24 hours ago   Up 24 hours
0ba613d35ec3   postgres:15.1-alpine   25 hours ago   Up 25 hours
```

25 hours ago is when `docker compose up --build --detach` was last called. 9 hours ago most likely coincides with the time when the problems arise. I'm trying to figure out why's that happening, but I haven't yet. Anyway, it shouldn't 'corrupt' the volume, should it?

How would you approach debugging this? Does anyone have a hunch what that might be?

If that matters, I'm hosted on a very cheap HDD VPS - could it be the reason?

Comment: What is the output of `docker-compose logs nginx django`

Comment: @DrClaw just the fresh logs of the restarted services without any errors. I removed the restart policy and added Sentry to Django, waiting for something to happen.

Comment: You can also add volumes for logs in both nginx and django.